# How convert list element to list?

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

Original cat looks like this:

```
cat = ['a','a,b,c','c,d,e,f']
```

I want to convert it to:

```
cat = [['a'],['a','b','c'],['c','d','e','f']]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by `list comprehension` as:

```
>>> cat = ['a','a,b,c','c,d,e,f']
>>> [c.split(',') for c in cat]
[['a'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f']]
```

**Alternatively**, you may also use `lambda` function with `map` to achieve this:

```
>>> map(lambda x: x.split(','), cat)
[['a'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) each string:

```
result = [s.split(',') for s in cat]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
cat = ['a','a,b,c','c,d,e,f']
newlist = [a.split(',') for a in cat]
print(newlist)
>>> [['a'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f']]
```